# Why include() function returning false always?

Tags: javascript, include

This is my code, This isCurrent?InvoiceIdStored always returing false no matter what ever the values I put for id

```
const invoiceIds = [4,2];
const isCurrentInvoiceIdStored = invoiceIds.includes(id => id === 4);
```

What I want is to check the given number is in this array or not?

Comment: Includes doesn't accept a function afaik. Try `.includes(4)`? Maybe you mean to use [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead?

Comment: invoiceIds is a string collection and doesn't have the property named id

Comment: @Venkat the function isn't looking for a property called id. `id` is just the name of the variable. It probably could have been anything

Comment: Thanks, but what is the different between .some and .includes?

Comment: @Theepag `some` "tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by a provided function", whereas `includes` "determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries".

Comment: @Theepag -  Includes used to find whether a certain value is available or not. Some function can take a function and check whether the value exists for the given function. 

[Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) vs
[Some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) ***the value to search for*** as parameter but you are passing a call back function as parameter:

```js
const invoiceIds = [4,2];
const isCurrentInvoiceIdStored = invoiceIds.includes(4);
console.log(isCurrentInvoiceIdStored);
```

**OR:** You probably wanted to use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which accepts ***a function to test for each element***

```js
const invoiceIds = [4,2];
const isCurrentInvoiceIdStored = invoiceIds.some(id => id == 4);
console.log(isCurrentInvoiceIdStored);
```

Comment: What is the diff between some and includes?

Comment: @Theepag, the difference is you can apply some logic when use `some()`.

Comment: @Theepag it's like asking the question "do some of the array elements pass my test?". `includes` asks the question "does the array contain the exact provided value?"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `invoiceIds.includes(4)` instead of `invoiceIds.includes(id => id === 4)`.